# Await doesn't wait

Tags: javascript

```
function resolveAfter2Seconds(x) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(x);
        }, 2000);
    });
}

async function f1() {
    var x = await resolveAfter2Seconds(10);
    console.log(x); 
}

f1();
let x =  3;
```

Why do we see the following scenario?

1. Entering the f1. Stops on await.
2. Returns from f1 (console.log(x) command doesn't execute)
3. assign 3 to x (ERROR! await skipped, js steps forward)
4. Return to f1 on line "console.log(x)". Print x.

Why JS not waiting on await and steps forward? May you give me an advice?

Comment: Because you didn't `await` your outer function call.

Comment: @4castle, **await** should be used in async function.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`f1` is asynchronous (the await only occurs *within* that asynchronous context). Therefore, `f1()` is executed, and because it's async, the `let x = 3;` line executes immediately without waiting.

If you also `await` the call to `f1()`, it should do what you're expecting. However in order to use `await`, you must wrap that code inside another `async` function, and then execute that function.

Demo (no await):

```js
function resolveAfter2Seconds(x) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(x);
        }, 2000);
    });
}

async function f1() {
    var x = await resolveAfter2Seconds(10);
    console.log(x); 
}

f1();
let x =  3;
console.log(x);
```

Working version (with extra await):

```js
function resolveAfter2Seconds(x) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(x);
    }, 2000);
  });
}

async function f1() {
  var x = await resolveAfter2Seconds(10);
  console.log(x);
}

async function f2() {
  await f1();
  let x = 3;
  console.log(x);
};

f2();
```

You can't use `await` outside an `async` context...so at the end of the chain *something* has to be async. The bottom line is, anything you want to be waiting until after the `f1()` executes must be either

- inside the `f2()` function after the `await`, or
- executed within a `.then()` callback attached to the promise.

Comment: But if I put "let y = 4" after "f2()" it instantly moves to "let y = 4" and skips promise!

Comment: yes. That's because f2() is now the async function. You've just replicated your original situation. You can't use `await` outside an `async` context...so at the end of the chain _something_ has to be async. Bottom line is, anything you want to be waiting until after the f1() executes must be either a) inside the f2() function after the await, or b) executed within a `.then()` callback attached to the promise.

Comment: @ADyson you should make that comment a part of your answer.

Answer (score 4):

More simpler

```js
(async function() {

  function resolveAfter2Seconds(x) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve(x);
      }, 2000);
    });
  }

  async function f1() {
    var x = await resolveAfter2Seconds(10);
    console.log(x);
  }


  await f1();
  let x = 3; 
  console.log(x);
})();
```